# Declare issues in MS SQL SERVER Report Builder

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, reportbuilder

I am having issues with an error message constantly occurring, which states "Must declare scalar variable "@station".

Also, I am trying to set **"specific" stations** into "units" via Boolean but I don't know if that is the correct way to use the parameter "@station"

If someone could point me in the right direction I would seriously appreciate it.

```
    declare @Dbgn datetime,
    @Dend datetime;
set @Dbgn = @dateFrom + @ShiftStart;
set @Dend = @Dbgn + 1;

if @station = 1
begin
  -- set (Fields!unit.Value =(695, 696, 697 ,698, 651, 652, 653, 654, 655, 656, 657));
end
else
begin
  -- set (Fields!unit.Value =(51, 52, 221, 531, 532, 533, 534));
end
begin
SELECT  operator,
    unit,
    case
         when isNull(ScriptRate,0) > 0 and isNull(ItemRate,0) = 0 then 'Scripts'
         when isNull(ScriptRate,0) = 0 and isNull(ItemRate,0) > 0 then 'Items'
         when isNull(ScriptRate,0) > 0 and isNull(ItemRate,0) > 0 then '-X-'
         else '?'
    end  AS Type,
    SUM(ISNULL(numorders, 0))    AS totalorders,
    SUM(ISNULL(numscripts, 0))   AS totalscripts,
    SUM(ISNULL(numitems, 0))     AS totalitems,
    SUM(ISNULL(minuteslogon, 0)) AS totalminutes,
    case 
         when activityhour = 0 then 24
         else activityhour
    end as activityhour,
    sum( case
         when isNull(ScriptRate,0) > 0 and isNull(ItemRate,0) = 0 then ss.numscripts
         when isNull(ScriptRate,0) = 0 and isNull(ItemRate,0) > 0 then ss.NUMITEMS
         else 0
    end )     AS totalpvitems,
    avg( case
         when isNull(ScriptRate,0) > 0 and isNull(ItemRate,0) = 0 then unit.ScriptRate
         when isNull(ScriptRate,0) = 0 and isNull(ItemRate,0) > 0 then unit.ItemRate
         else 0
    end )     AS targetRate
FROM    mck_hvs.stationstats ss with( nolock ),
    mck_hvs.unit with( nolock )
WHERE   ss.unit = unit.unitno
    and activitytype > 1
    and ( createdate >= cast( @Dbgn as datetime) )
    and ( logofftime <= cast( @Dend as datetime) )

GROUP BY operator,
    unit,
    case
         when isNull(ScriptRate,0) > 0 and isNull(ItemRate,0) = 0 then 'Scripts'
         when isNull(ScriptRate,0) = 0 and isNull(ItemRate,0) > 0 then 'Items'
         when isNull(ScriptRate,0) > 0 and isNull(ItemRate,0) > 0 then '-X-'
         else '?'
    end,
    case 
         when activityhour = 0 then 24
         else activityhour
    end
ORDER BY operator asc,
    unit desc,
    activityhour
end
```

Comment: Where you declared this variable? @station

Comment: Well, in the code you posted you haven't declared `@station`

Comment: I declared it as a boolean but it was stating it invalid. How do I declare it in order for it to follow the rest of the syntax ex "@Dbgn datetime" ?  @Lamak

Comment: Where do you set @station = 0 | 1?

Comment: Other than the @station issue (declare it as a bit, set it to 0 or 1 as needed), you also have an issue with the relationship between `mck_hvs.stationstats` and `mck_hvs.unit`. Specifically, you don't use any relationship between these two tables, which should generate a full CROSS JOIN (all rows in Table1 will be matched with all rows in Table2), which seems unlikely to be your intention.

Comment: Declaring @station as bit still flags the same error

Comment: @LaughingVergil

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that your code is that the variable '@station' was not declared but used. You need to declare @station

```
DECLARE @Dbgn datetime,
    @Dend datetime,
    @station int; -- Declare @station as an integer, assuming it's an 
integer parameter.

-- Set your other variables and parameters
SET @Dbgn = @dateFrom + @ShiftStart;
SET @Dend = @Dbgn + 1;

-- The rest of your code follows
if @station = 1
begin
  -- Your logic for station = 1
end
else
begin
  -- Your logic for station not equal to 1
end

 -- The SELECT statement and the rest of your code follows
```